# Get current tab url in chrome extension in background script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to get the tab url, whenever user switches a tab. I have tried the methods that are provided in different questions, but they work when user clicks a button in popup. I want to do this continuously in the background context.

I have tried this

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function (tabId) {
var url;
var tab_id = tabId.tabId;
chrome.tabs.get(tab_id, function(tab){
    url = tab.url;
});

doStuff(url);
});
```

but the url is still undefined. Any ideas ?

Comment: I am just guessing here, but I bet the callback passed to chrome.tabs.get hasn't fired by the time you call doStuff(url). I suggest you put doStuff(url) inside your callback.

Comment: yeah that worked, can you place this in answer so that i can mark it

Comment: I you want to do custom stuff use the callback answer, however if you want to do something in e.g. chrome event callback, you would need to *store a map of `tabId => URL` using tab create/update events*, because in events regarding request/response etc. tabId is might as well be all you get and **asynchronous** chrome.tabs.get would be no longer sufficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try placing the call to doStuff(url) inside the callback function supplied to the chrome.tabs.get() call.

Answer (score 1):

You can only read URLs this way if you have the `"tabs"` permission.